# How can I rename an element (e.g.: Association) in Acceleo

Tags: associations, element, rename, renaming, acceleo

I've been working with Acceleo 3.2.2 for awhile lately but this is my first approach and there are many basic points that I'm still missing.. 
In my .mtl file I have created a new association for a class:

```
[anAssocClass.createAssociation(true, snk.aggregation, snk.name, 1, 1, snk.type, 
                                    true, snk.aggregation, anAssocClass.name, src.lower, src.upper) /]
```

How can I set a name to this new association?
The API provides the operations

- setValue(stereotype: Stereotype, propertyName: String, newValue: String)
- eSet(feature: EStructuralFeature, newValue: OclAny)

but I don't know if they are what I'm in need of and how to use them neither (which stereotype/feature and how can I get them?)...

Does anyone know how to help me?

Comment: I found out myself: while using Java services there are more available operations than those provided while in an .mtl template. Among these, the method setName(String name) shows up.